# Modify a value of a variable passed by reference

Tags: php

I want to be able to modify a value of a variable that is passed by reference to a function.

```
<?php
    function invoke($what) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array($what, $args);
    }

    function page(&$page) {
        return $page;
    }

    $page = array();
    $page['context'] = 'view';
    invoke('page', $page);
    ?>
```

When I call invoke(), I'm getting the warning:
Parameter 1 to page() expected to be a reference, value given in invoke()

Please what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Consider refactoring your code like this: `function invoke($what, array $args = array()) { return call_user_func_array($what, $args); } invoke('page', array(&$page));`. This way, you will pass a reference to `$page` instead of its value. (Your implementation is also incorrect - your `$args` still includes the `$what` as the first argument).

Comment: Thanks. For curiosity sake, what's the role of func_get_args()? My understanding is that it gets whatever other arguments passed to invoke(). In my case, that will be $page.

Comment: [`func_get_args`](http://us.php.net/func_get_args) will get *all* the arguments of the current function, not just variadic ones.

Comment: So why do I still need to pass `$args = array()` explicitly to invoke()? func_get_args sees two args. call_user_func_array sees 'page()' and passes to 'page()' whatever is contained in $args.

Comment: You need to *explicitly* pass arguments by reference into `invoke` (which is what passing `array(&$page)` does in my example, an explicit reference). PHP cannot automatically decide to take them by reference because it doesn't know which function you'll invoke and can't check its signature. You could do `invoke('page', &$page)`, but call-time pass by reference is a bad thing and was removed from PHP 5.4.

Comment: @DCoder I'm pretty sure call-time reference wouldn't work here either. `func_get_args()` returns an array containing copies of the arguments. References are not preserved.

Comment: @cleong: you're right, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

you  are passing two value in function invoke() and getting only one use the function lke `function invoke($what,$second)` or just pass only one like `invoke($page);`

Comment: Not necessarily. invoke($page) won't work. invoke() is meant to call page(), then pass in the value of $page. That's what `call_user_func_array($what, $args)` is doing there.

Comment: @drecute he is getting the warning an  this is causes the warning

Comment: @drecute am i missing anywhere ? or is my answer not solving your problem ?